# How to make categories list that contains products in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an e-commerce app, and I want to have categories where each category contains different products list based on the category, how I would do that ?

Here is my code

this one called ProductsService.js

```
const PRODUCTS = [
{
    id: 100,
    name: 'ReactProX Headset',
    price: 350,
    image: require('../assets/products/product-1.png'),
    categoryId: "1",
    description: 'A headset combines a headphone with microphone. Headsets are made with either a single-earpiece (mono) or a double-earpiece (mono to both ears or stereo).'
},
{
    id: 101,
    name: 'FastLane Toy Car',
    price: 600,
    image: require('../assets/products/product-2.png'),
    categoryId: "2",
    description: 'A model car, or toy car, is a miniature representation of an automobile. Other miniature motor vehicles, such as trucks, buses, or even ATVs, etc. are often included in this general category.'
},
{
    id: 102,
    name: 'SweetHome Cupcake',
    price: 2,
    image: require('../assets/products/product-3.png'),
    categoryId: "1",
    description: 'A cupcake (also British English: fairy cake; Hiberno-English: bun; Australian English: fairy cake or patty cake[1]) is a small cake designed to serve one person.'
}
];
export function getProducts(categoryId) {
    return PRODUCTS;
}
export function getProduct(id) {
    return PRODUCTS.find((product) => (product.id == id));
}
```

this one called Product.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, Image, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
export function Product({name, price, image, categoryId ,onPress}) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={onPress}>
      <Image
        style={styles.thumb}
        source={image}
      />
      <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.price}>$ {price}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

this one called CategoriesList.js

```
    import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  FlatList,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Product } from '../components/Product.js';
import { getProducts } from '../services/ProductsService.js';



export function CategoriesList({ route, navigation }) {

  function renderProduct({item: product}) {
    return (
      <Product {...product} 
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {
          productId: product.id,
        });
      }}
      />
    );
  }

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(getProducts(route.params));
  });

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.productsList}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.productsListContainer}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      data={products}
      renderItem={renderProduct}
    />
    
  );

}
```

I guess the secret is here

```
export function getProducts(categoryId) {
return PRODUCTS;
}
```

but I don't really know how to do it, any help?

Comment: Hey  I tried to read through your JS, but it’s not fully clear what you want to achieve. The data looks like it’s pulled from a template, so it doesn’t give us much insight. Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: Hey sir, the output will be products list, and the code works fine. However, I don't want all the product list, I want only a product list based on specific category number

Comment: I can't believe how much the internet content is really poor in terms of react native. You can't find solutions even for simple questions.

Comment: Well, you can try PRODUCTS.filter(p=>p.categoryId===categoryId).

Comment: I made like this just for testing return PRODUCTS.filter(p=>p.categoryId==="2"), it doesn't work. However, if I made it like this return PRODUCTS, it returns all products

Comment: This isn't so much of a React Native question as a Javascript question. @OFRBG gave the correct answer for filtering an array. If you need more help, explain what doesn't work about your filter, or you can read more [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjwrNHE6-f1AhUQHTQIHVGKAZMQFnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw2QKYd1Sc9CyBgTVtEH2ksT).

Comment: Do you think we do this in the back end? I mean we select products based on specific category from the database, then we return product list of this specific category. In this way we minimize the server loading by calling specific products list instead of calling them all. Do you think this is right?